# Is there a way to read incoming Windows notifications with python?

Tags: python, windows, notifications

I would like to write a python script that listens to all incoming windows notifications and returns their content, so far i found nothing that works with python and would like to know if it's even possible.

Comment: Are you trying to obtain notifications from a given service or ALL the windows notifications?

Comment: Only from one given service

Comment: which one would be that one?, it is better to try to hook into that service, since Windows Notifications seems to not be made to be readable from other applications.

Comment: im talking about discord, the problem with discord is:  catching the notifications requires linking my account with my python script, which isnt allowed according to their TOS.